# How to marshall LPVOID from external dll function in C#

Tags: c#, dll, marshalling

I have this dll function signature:

```
extern BOOL __stdcall ReadTag(LPVOID values)
```

How can I map LPVOID pointer to C# external method?

Comment: This function appears to be designed to corrupt memory as a feature, use a telephone to ask for a better api or manual.

Comment: have you tried `IntPtr`? `LPVOID` should translate to `IntPtr`

Comment: What is very strange for me is that function should accept many types: int, short, byte array, I should read everything from that method, therefore I cannot set a defined type! Maybe this is why Hans wrote that nice comment.

Comment: It has been a while for this question. Anyone has been able to figure this out?